# Magento - is a block always needed for a widget?

Tags: magento, widget

I just started to develop Magento widgets and thereby I came to this problem/question:

It is possible to tell a Magento widget not to use a block-class and directly render a template file?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block is needed. If you don't want to create a new block, just give block type as `cms/block`. Remember, in your phtml template files, then you will not have your custom functions call by using `$this` (as `$this` references to Block).

Comment: can you tell me how exactly i can use this predefined block? if i try type="cms/block" in the widget.xml the template is not rendered